# IFS Separator in Variables

Tags: shell, variable

A string is passed to a shell script which should add the date and separate the words by a given character.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SEPARATOR=';'

# change separator
ORG_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$SEPARATOR

# todays date
TODAY=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y")
echo "date: " $TODAY

# concatenate command line arguments
DATA_STRING="$*"
echo "data: " "$DATA_STRING" "(correct)"
echo "data: "  $DATA_STRING  "(wrong: missing separator)"

# date + command line arguments
FINAL_STRING="${TODAY}${SEPARATOR}"${DATA_STRING}""
echo "date+data: " $FINAL_STRING

# restore original separator
IFS=$ORG_IFS
```

A call would look like this:

```
myscript.sh apple banana cherry
```

The output now is:

```
date:  07.09.2019
data:  apple;banana;cherry (correct)
data:  apple banana cherry (wrong: missing separator)
date+data:  07.09.2019 apple banana cherry
```

The desired result is:

```
07.09.2019;apple;banana;cherry
```

Being fairly new to Linux shell programming I do not understand how to keep the seperator when concatenating variables to a string.

I've tried a lot of combinations with and without the *"..."* but I don't understand what this actually does to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar way as `$*` inserts a character in a concatenation of arguments an **un quoted** expansion removes characters from an string and every removal breaks the string into separated arguments.

```
$ var=1234567890
$ IFS=368
$ echo "$var" $var
1234567890 12 45 7 90
$ printf '<%s> ' "$var" $var
<1234567890> <12> <45> <7> <90>
```

Comment: Thanks. So I just need to keep the quotes to see the separator in the result.

Comment: @Sören correct. There are very seldom situations where you should _not_ double quote variable expansions. See e.g. [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)